# Using paperclip + papercrop with specific style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can I set the crop of an image only in a specific style?

This are my styles:

```
{
    :thumb => attachment.instance.thumb_style,
    :small => attachment.instance.small_style,
    :normal => attachment.instance.normal_style
}
```

So when I crop the image, the only style that will change is the **:thumb**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

I was trying to use `reprocess!` inside the model with an `after_asset_post_process` but it was creating an infinite loop, so what I did was:

```
img = Paperclip::Attachment.new("asset", instance, {:path => ':rails_root/public/system/assets/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension', :styles => {:normal => "620x"} })
img.reprocess!
```

After I saved the asset in the controller.